# Team Foundation Server TF31003 error

Tags: tfs, server

I want to Add Team Foundation Solution but I am getting error .I have tried  different solutions. But I couldn't find a solution.

[image]

Comment: Like the message tell you, it's a matter of permissions. Did you provide the good credential in the popup requiring to log in visualstudio.com? Or perhaps the fact that protocol "http" is checked instead of "https".... Look around that.

Comment: Thanks . But I made logging in visual studio.com. I tried protocol https but I getting same error.

Comment: Which version of VS/Team Explorer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using one of the following versions of Visual Studio to connect to VSTS:

   - Visual Studio "15"
   - Visual Studio 2015
   - Visual Studio 2013
   - Visual Studio 2012
   - Visual Studio 2010, requires [Service Pack 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and [KB2662296](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2662296)
   - Visual Studio 2008 SP1, requires [GDR update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2673642)
2. Try clearing the cookies for your browser, or try logging off your client computer or workstation and logging back on.
3. To run Visual Studio under an account that is different from your logged on Windows account, open the context menu for devenv.exe to access your run as options.

More details for this error, check the article below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244133.aspx

Comment: Thanks , Try clearing the cookies for your browser - This is solution. All of them browser in pc